# SSRS ReportViewer: ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found

Tags: session, reporting-services, reportviewer

Our current MVC 4 application (windows 7) uses an IFRAME to display the MS report viewer control (version 10.0.0.0). I am using the SSRS web service to retrieve a list of folders and reports from the root folder. The parameters for each report are queried and displayed using our custom UI. The parameters are passed back to the reportviewer to render the report. Everything works perfect when running the web and SSRS servers locally (using both IE 11.096 and Chrome 33.0.1750.154), however after deploying to our test web and ssrs servers, the report viewer appears to begin to render (loading gif is shown) but then displays the message 'ASP .NET Session expired or could not be found.'

There are dozens of forum postings regarding this issue. So far I have tried and verified the following without any success:

- Application is using SessionMode=SQLServer, cookieless=false
- Increased timeout=3000 in web.config
- Set ReportViewer AsyncRendering = false
- Set ReportViewer KeepSessionAlive = true
- Check for postback in the Page_load of the report viewer aspx.cs
- Checked the IIS logs for errors
- Found errors in the Reporting Server event log:
- ** Report Server (MSSQLSERVER) cannot load the SQLPDW extension
- ** Report Server (MSSQLSERVER) cannot load the TERADATA extension.
- ** These errors do not appear to have any impact on session problem
- Modified web.config on Reporting Server (ReportServer) to turn
  SessionState=On
- Modified web.config on Reporting Server (ReportManager) from
  SessionMode=InProc to use SessionMode=SQLServer
- Examined the ReportingServer logs (noted all successful web service
  calls)
- Verified one worker process in Application pool
- When viewing frame source there is a message "The Report Viewer Web
  Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application..."
  however the following handler entries are present:
- add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*"
  type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,
  Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
- add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler"
  preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"
  path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
  type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,
  Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
- ** This message is also displayed locally (not sure if it is a problem or not)
- Restarted IIS / ReportServer
- Report executes fine on the Report Server using Report Manager
- Report executes fine externally within Report Manager
- Report executes fine within the MVC application running locally
- When I created an event handler for the reportViewer
  (OnReportError="HandleError") the code in this handler did not get
  executed and the viewer (using Chrome) displayed a blank page (no
  error displayed) The same result occurred using IE (no error
  displayed) but the toolbar images were also misaligned/disabled.

I have tried most if not all of the suggestions I have found. Everything runs perfect locally in either browser. Publishing to the server is when the errors occur. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Is the web application and ssrs server on the same domain and being accessed using the same protocol, i.e. http/https?

Comment: Yes. In our test environment, the web application and the SSRS server are on the same domain using http. When the application is moved to production it will be using https.

Comment: One of my colleagues discovered that the web.config deployed on our DEV server had the following entry:     <pages enableSessionState="ReadOnly" validateRequest="false"> Once I removed this entry, everything worked.